# Mac でターミナルから data スキーム URI を既定ブラウザで開く方法

Tags: macos

Mac のターミナルから既定ブラウザで URI を開く場合、open コマンドで以下のようにできます。

```
$ open http://example.com/
```

ですが、同じことを data: で始まる URI ではうまくできません。
ローカルからファイルとして探してしまっているようです。

```
$ open data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==
The file /Users/yuya/src/github.com/yuya-takeyama/qrcat/data:text/plain does not exist.
zsh: command not found: base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==
```

これをうまく実行する方法はないでしょうか。
具体的なブラウザは指定せずに、既定のブラウザで開くようにしたいです。

Comment: `open 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=='` とするとどうなりますか？(`data:〜` をシングルクォートで囲みます)

Comment: 試してみましたが、シングルクォートで囲まないのと同じ結果になりました。エスケープ等による問題ではないようです。

Comment: そうですか、、実はこちらの環境(Linux + firefox)で同じようなことをしていて、`firefox 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=='` とすると、firefox 上に `Hello, World!` と表示されます。

Comment: @heliac2001 ブラウザを明示的に指定すればMacでも同じようにできると思いますが、[`open` コマンド](http://macwiki.sourceforge.jp/wiki/index.php/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89/open)はそのファイルに対応するデフォルトのアプリケーションを起動しますから、 `data:...` に対応するアプリケーションが見つけられないのだと思います 。

Comment: なるほど、、OSX でデフォルトブラウザを取得するコマンドがあれば、`open -a $(get_default_browser) data:...` とかできるのですが、Apple script で取得する方法ぐらいしか見当たりませんね。。。

Answer (score 1):

英語版SOに同様の質問を見つけました。

[osx - Open an .html file with default browser using Bash on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250717/2818869)

ここでは、 [DefaultApplication](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/defaultApplication/defaultApplication.html) というサードパーティのコマンドを使った方法が紹介されています。これを使えばこのように書けるのではないでしょうか（手元にMacがないので検証できませんが）。

```sh
open -a "$(/usr/local/bin/DefaultApplication -url 'http:')" "data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=="
```

Perl や AppleScript を使ってデフォルトブラウザを取得する方法もあるようです。

[osx - Discover default browser programmatically on Mac - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/613362/423291)